# Is there a way to open a file stored in andorid assets with a specific application?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to open a file from assets with an application using the code below:

```
                            String fileUri = "file:///android_asset/extensions/file.novabackup";
             
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fileUri), "application/octet-stream");
                            intent.setPackage("com.teslacoilsw.launcher");
                            
                            startActivity(intent);
```

However, it does nothing and simply returns me to the MainActivity. I've also granted READ and WRITE access.

Comment: The android_asset thing  only works within your own app, and really only with a webview.  You could however write a ContentProvider that would allow access to any data you want, including an asset file

Comment: @GabeSechan I am trying open a file from assets with an application called Nova Launcher [similar to "Open With"]. I don't know what the <provider> would be for that particular application